# Use angular template cache with browserify

Tags: javascript, angularjs, caching, gruntjs, browserify

I am building a small angular app with browserify and `ui-router`. As I don't want to use a server, I want to store all my templates using angular's `$templateCache` like this:

```
exports.templateCache = ["$templateCache", function($templateCache) {
  'use strict';

  $templateCache.put('partials/someState.html',
    "myHtmlCode"
  );
}];
```

To populate the cache, I use grunt to look into my `partials` folder, grab all the html and load it into the cache with `grunt-angular-templates`:

```
 ngtemplates:  {
  myApp: {
    cwd: 'dist/',
    src: 'partials/**.html',
    dest: 'src/js/templates/templates.js',
    options: {
      bootstrap:  function(module, script) {
        return 'exports.templateCache = ["$templateCache", function($templateCache) {\n' +
          script +
          '}];'
      }
    }
  }
},
```

I then use browersify to combine all my js together:

```
browserify: {
  dist: {
    files: {
      'dist/js/app.js': [
          'src/js/templates/**',
          'src/app.js'
          ],
    }
  }
},
```

This is working so far but this workflow looks very unwieldy to me: I have an intermediary step where I create the `templates.js` file in my `src` directory and I have hard-coded code in my grunt file.

Is there any way to do this more elegantly? Does browserify come with built in solutions to tackle this problem?

Comment: Dealing with a similar issue. Have you found a solution yet?

Answer (score 3):

[browserify-ng-html2js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserify-ng-html2js) has been designed to resolve this problem.

Simply add in package.json :

```
"browserify": {
    "transform": ["browserify-ng-html2js"]
 }
```

And you'll see if it walks the talks :)

Comment: There is also **'ngify'** [github](https://github.com/majgis/ngify),  another Browserify transform.  `browserify().transform(require('ngify')).bundle()...`

Comment: Both of these transforms specify the filename as the module name. This makes it hard to use as the app grows.

Comment: [ngify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngify) was just updated to allow relative paths

Answer (score 0):

Try transform for browserify that give you possibility to require html file (eg. Stringify). Then you can require('yourPartial.html') as string:

```
$templateCache.put('yourPartialId', require('./partials/yourPartial.html'));

// html file
<div ng-include=" 'yourPartialId' "></div>
```